# javac not recognized after trying everything I can find ( not duplicate )

Tags: java, cmd, java-8, path, javac

I would like to start by saying please do not mark this as a duplicate. I have looked at all of the "duplicates" I can find and NONE of the solutions have worked.

I am trying to get my java path set up so that javac will work, I have:

- put it in the path
- added "JAVA_HOME"
- checked the version multiple times and reinstalled them
- uninstalled older versions
- put the bin, the program files\java path, and even moved the javac file into the path and nothing is working

I have jdk 1.8.0_251

I have no idea why it is not working. If someone more experienced at setting up Java could help that would be great. I am extremely frustrated as I have been working on this for a while and it had worked fine previously.

Comment: After modifying path, have you tried turning your computer off and on again? (seriously)

Comment: I suggest deleting all java related paths and add a PATH variable to the java/bin folder of your preferred version.

Comment: Type `set p` and `where java*` and post the results. Duplicates are used so people searching for the same terms as in your question find the page and the linked answer.

Comment: It's been half a day and still no useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `PATH` environment variable with java installation directory
like `...\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin`

Comment: Of course its a duplicate. We've seen it asked a thousand times. You don't provide any hard information. If you had you would have gotten an answer in comments - then it would be marked as duplicate.